# TorQ: How to use dataloader partitioning with separate tables that have different date ranges?

Tags: kdb, torq

I'm trying to populate a prices and quotes database using AquaQ's TorQ. For this purpose I use the [.loader.loadallfiles function](https://aquaqanalytics.github.io/TorQ/utilities/#dataloaderq). The difference being that `prices` is daily data and `quotes` is more intraday e.g. FX rates.

I do the loading as follows:

```
/- check the location of database directory
hdbdir:hsym `$getenv[`KDBHDB]
/hdbdir:@[value;`hdbdir;`:hdb]
rawdatadir:hsym `$getenv[`KDBRAWDATA]

target:hdbdir;

rawdatadir:hsym `$("" sv (getenv[`KDBRAWDATA]; "prices"));
.loader.loadallfiles[`headers`types`separator`tablename`dbdir`partitioncol`partitiontype`dataprocessfunc!(`date`sym`open`close`low`high`volume;"DSFFFFF";enlist ",";`prices;target;`date;`year;{[p;t] `date`sym`open`close`low`high`volume xcols update volume:"i"$volume from t}); rawdatadir];

rawdatadir:hsym `$("" sv (getenv[`KDBRAWDATA]; "quotes"));
.loader.loadallfiles[`headers`types`separator`tablename`dbdir`partitioncol`partitiontype`dataprocessfunc!(`date`sym`bid`ask;"ZSFF";enlist ",";`quotes;target;`date;`year;{[p;t] `date`sym`bid`ask`mid xcols update mid:(bid+ask)%2.0 from t}); rawdatadir];
```

and this works fine. However when loading the database I get errors attemping to select from either table. The reason is that for some partitions there aren't any `prices` or or there aren't any `quotes` data. e.g. attempting to:

```
quotes::`date`sym xkey select from quotes;
```

fails with an error saying the the partition for year e.g. `hdb/2000/` doesn't exist which is true, there are only `prices` for year 2000 and no `quotes`

As I see there are two possible solutions but neither I know how to implement:

1. Tell `.loader.loadallfiles` to create empty schema for quotes and prices in partitions for which there isn't any data.
2. While loading the database, gracefully handle the case where there is no data for a given partition i.e. `select from ... where ignore empty partitions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `` .Q.chk[`:hdb] ``

Where `` `:hdb `` is the filepath of your HDB

This fills in missing tables, which will then allow you to preform queries.

Alternatively you can use [`.Q.bv`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qbv-build-vp), where the wiki states:

> If your table exists in the latest partition (so there is a prototype
>   for the schema), then you could use `.Q.bv[]` to create empty tables
>   on the fly at run-time without having to create those empties on disk.

Comment: That worked perfectly! thank you so much!! I used the "cleaner" `.Q.bv[];` alternative.

Comment: For more on .Q.chk:  http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qchk-fill-hdb 

And for .Q.bv: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qbv-build-vp

Glad I could help!